# spring4D dependency injector with MVP

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I'm using Spring4D's dependency injector in something organized as MVP, in my view I have the interface reference of my presenter and in the create method of the presenter I have the injection of the view's interface in the constructor, the view is registered as a singleton, however, when creating and resolving the Presenter, the view is created again and enters a loop, is it possible to do this with Spring4D?

```
procedure RegisterTypes(const Container: TContainer);
begin
  Container.RegisterType<TConexao>.asSingleton;
  Container.RegisterType<TConversorService>;
  Container.RegisterType<TfrmConversorView>.AsSingleton();
  Container.RegisterType<TConversorUseCase>;

  container.Build;
end;
```

My View(Form)

```
type
  TfrmConversorView = class(TForm, IConversorView)
    JvStatusBar1: TJvStatusBar;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FService: IConversorService;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

...
procedure TfrmConversorView.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FService := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IConversorService>;
end;
```

My Presenter

```
Type
  TConversorService = Class(TInterfacedObject, IConversorService)
  Private
    FView: IConversorView;
    FUseCase: IConversorUseCase;

  Public

    Constructor Create(aView: IConversorView; aUseCase: IConversorUseCase);
  End;

implementation

{ TConversorService }

Constructor TConversorService.Create(aView: IConversorView; aUseCase: IConversorUseCase);
begin
  FView := aView;
  FUseCase := aUseCase;
end;
```

Tks.

I imagined that declaring as a singleton the existing instance of the object would be injected instead of creating a new one,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do service location which is a different Resolve chain from the one originally creating the view. That causes another creation of the `TConversorService` which is not marked as singleton.
Design your code as if you were doing pure DI - tinkering with the DI container without proper design and then stuffing service location into your code always leads to issues.

If you need a back reference to your `IConversorService` inside the view that gets injected into your `IConversorService` then the easiest way is to put a property onto your view which can be set inside of `TConversorService.Create`.